# Capture a dot with postgres regexp

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have these strings :

```
3           FD160497.   2016  abcd
3           FD160497   2016  abcd
```

I want to capture "FD", the digits, then the dot if it is present.

I tried this :

```
SELECT
    sqn[1] AS letters,
    sqn[2] AS digits,
    sqn[3] AS dot
FROM (
    SELECT
        regexp_matches(string, '.*?(FD)([0-9]{6})(\.)?.*') as sqn
    FROM
        mytable
) t;
```

(PostgreSQL 9.5.3)

"dot" column is `NULL` in both cases, and I really don't know why.
It works well on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/p5SCfm/1).

Comment: Try `regexp_matches(string, '.*(FD)([0-9]{6})(\.)?.*') as sqn` or even add a space before `F`.

Comment: Try using the greedy flag. If the greedy option isn´t set (= lazy), the dot matches the fewest chars possible. The dot will then be matched by the `.*` at the end. Alternatively you could add a space after the last question mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first lazy pattern made all quantifiers in the current branch lazy, so your pattern became equivalent to

```
.*?(FD)([0-9]{6})(\.)??.*?
                     ^^  ^
```

See its [demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/C0kiYp/1)

See the [*9.7.3.1. Regular Expression Details* excerpt](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-matching.html):

> ...matching is done in such a way that the branch, or whole RE, matches the longest or shortest possible substring as a whole. Once the length of the entire match is determined, the part of it that matches any particular subexpression is determined on the basis of the greediness attribute of that subexpression, with subexpressions starting earlier in the RE taking priority over ones starting later.

You need to use quantifiers consistently within one branch:

```
regexp_matches(string, '.*(FD)([0-9]{6})(\.)?.*') as sqn
```

or

```
regexp_matches(string, '.*[[:blank:]](FD)([0-9]{6})(\.)?.*') as sqn
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C0kiYp/2)

Comment: Thank you, I think I choosed to write `'.*?(FD) ...` because I had other patterns to match...

Comment: In any case, you will have to write a more verbose pattern in that case. You can't mix greedy and lazy modifers in one branch.