# PostgreSQL regex not so non-greedy

Tags: regex, postgresql

I querying a postgresql data base and the regex syntax seems strange.

Why does the following expression return `'jcidopcjksd               jp'` and not `'jcidopcjksd'`?

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE ( 'jcidopcjksd               jp', '(^.*?)(\s+)(.*)', '\1');
```

Comment: it should work properly, can you create a reproducible example ?

Comment: Are you interested in the reason or the solution? Use `select REGEXP_REPLACE ( 'jcidopcjksd               jp', '^(\S*)(\s+)(.*)', '\1');` to solve it. Or even `substring ( 'jcidopcjksd               jp', '^\S*')`

Comment: @CodeManiac, I am just running the above in DBeaver with a connection to a PostgreSQL data base.  Not sure how to make a working example.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks. Yes, I was keen to understand why but, the solution is also nice.

Comment: [Here is my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41169676/3832970) explaining why it happens. Basically, you used `'(^.*?)(\s+?)(.*?)'` and only removed one space with your `REGEXP_REPLACE` command. `substring( 'jcidopcjksd jp', '^\S*')` seems to be a proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that when you use a lazy operator in the first group, all the other groups become lazy as well:

```
=# select REGEXP_MATCHES ( 'jcidopcjksd               jp', '(^.*)(\s+)(.*)');
            regexp_matches            
--------------------------------------
 {"jcidopcjksd              "," ",jp}
(1 row)

=# select REGEXP_MATCHES ( 'jcidopcjksd               jp', '(^.*?)(\s+)(.*)');
    regexp_matches    
----------------------
 {jcidopcjksd," ",""}
(1 row)
```

I don't know why is that though.

Comment: Not seems like, but it did. [I have explained it already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41169676/3832970).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I upvoted your answer but this one is a lot more understandable